# Create a QImage from a BITMAPINFO and an uchar* data

Tags: c++, qt, winapi, qimage, bitmapdata

I am trying to load an image that is given to me as a `BITMAPINFO*` and a `uchar` array.
The documentation states that it is a **standard Microsoft device independent bitmap (DIB) with 8-bit pixels and a 256-entry color table**.

I am curently able to open this image through:

```
BITMAPINFO* bmih = givenBITMAPINFO;
uchar* data = givenData;

QImage img = QImage(data, bmih->biWidth, bmih->biHeight, QImage::Format_Grayscale8);
```

But I have two problems with that:

1. the image is in `QImage::Format_Grayscale8` when the documentation states an 8-bit pixels and a 256-entry color table;
2. the image is upside down and mirrored. This come from the way the bitmap data is stored in Win32.

Anyone knows how I can load properly this image?

Comment: The color information for an 8-bit DIB is stored in a color palette. That color palette follows the `BITMAPINFOHEADER` in a standard bitmap file. Unless the pointer you have points at a `BITMAPINFOHEADER` followed by the color palette there is no way for you to reconcile the color information.

Comment: Okay, I think I can get the color table from the ```BITMAPINFO```. But then the image is backward, what would be the most efficient way to load it streight?

Comment: It doesn't appear that any of the `QImage` c'tors are capable of flipping the image, so you would have to apply [QImage::mirrored](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#mirrored) as a second step. Also note that there is [QImage::setColorTable](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#setColorTable). In combination with a [QImage::Format_Indexed8](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#Format-enum) image format you should be able to construct your image.

Comment: Does the QImage::mirrored() have a good complexity or should I use another library?

Comment: If in doubt, measure. Vertically flipping an image inevitably results in copying *all* pixel data in memory. Any imaging library is going to have to do this.

Comment: You should edit your question to clarify that you really have a `BITMAPINFO`, and not just a `BITMAPINFOHEADER`. Otherwise, as IInspectable pointed out, your answer isn't really correct.

Answer (score 0):

By casting the provided header to a `BITMAPINFO` instead of a `BITMAPINFOHEADER` I have access to the color table and then apply a trasformation to get a streight image:

```
BITMAPINFO* bmi = givenHeader;
uchar* data = givenData;

QImage img = QImage(data, bmi->bmiHeader.biWidth, bmi->bmiHeader.biHeight, QImage::Format_Indexed8);

img.setColorCount(256);
for (int i=0; i<256; ++i){
    RGBQUAD* rgbBmi = bmi->bmiColors;
    img.setColor(i, qRgb(rgbBmi[i].rgbRed, rgbBmi[i].rgbGreen, rgbBmi[i].rgbBlue))
}

img = img.mirrored(false, true);
```

Comment: While this may solve *your* specific problem, it is not a general solution. The question states the all you have is a `BITMAPINFOHEADER*`, where this solution requires a client to have a full `BITMAPINFO*`.